# How to get Pull request changes to local editor?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have created a branch : **test_branch** from master. Done some changes to code in **test_branch** and commited it and created a pull request.

Now I have a pull request in this format : https://something.com/something/abcd/pull/873/files

But in my editor , I cannot see my changes . **So how can I get those changes of pull request to my local editor?**

*PS : I have done a lot of commit after that on my local editor (as I am working on that pull request after some days). I have forgot to shash that on my local editor, so in my local editor I have nothing , all I have is this pull request , how can I get that change of pull request to my local editor?*

Comment: “how can I get that change of pull request to my local editor” Unclear what those words even mean. To see or run the content of the pull request locally, fetch the pull request branch and check out the desired commit.

Answer (score 3):

A *pull request* is a request (hence the "request" part of the name) one person makes to another.  Assume for the moment that you are the second person.  The request asks that you obtain (`git fetch`) and then `git merge` (fetch+merge = pull, hence the "pull" part of the name name) some commit(s) from some other Git repository.  That is, the person *making* the request is asking the person who could *execute* the request to run `git pull`, giving the name or URL of the request-maker's repository.

A *GitHub* pull request is this same basic idea, with a lot of GitHub-specific scaffolding added to make it easier for you, as a user of GitHub, to do the various steps involved.  "Raw" Git requires that you do the steps yourself, rather than clicking one big green <kbd>do things for me so I do not have to think</kbd> button.  The advantage of the GitHub style is that you don't have to think; the disdavantage is that so many people subsequently *don't think*.

If you *do* think about how this works, it eventually becomes obvious: you don't get the *changes* of a commit at all.  You either get the *commit*, or you don't get the commit.  That's what you can do with a commit: you can use `git fetch` to get it.  Once you *have* it, you can do more with it.

If you already *have* the commit—because you made it before sending it to *your own* GitHub repository, for instance, before making the pull request—you don't need to *get* it.  Just use your local Git to work with it.  If it's in *some other* GitHub repository, you will need to:

- add a *remote* so that you have a name for the URL, then
- use `git fetch` (and perhaps additional Git commands) to obtain (and perhaps do something with) the commit.<sup>1</sup>

When a GitHub pull request is in some repository that you can read like this, pick a name for that repository—a common remote name here is `upstream`, but the name is up to you—and run:

```
git remote add upstream <insert correct URL here>
```

(change the name from `upstream` if you like).  Then, use `git fetch`.  This requires a little bit of tricky stuff because of the fact that GitHub hides pull requests behind their own system:

```
git fetch upstream +refs/pull/<number>/head:refs/heads/pr<number>
```

for instance will create or force-update, in your own repository, a *branch* named `prnumber` from the pull request with the given number in their repository.

You now have the commit(s), in a branch called `prnumber`, and can work with them as usual.

Again, if *you* made the pull request, you *already have the commits*, probably in a branch, and you don't need to do all this.  Just work with them.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's possible to combine these steps using `git pull`, and to use a raw URL instead of a remote.  I recommend avoiding this until you are very familiar with all the steps that `git pull` runs.

Comment: The trick of fetching a PR commit by its PR number is clever but in practice isn't it usually unnecessary? GitHub tells you the name of the branch. Maybe it's more necessary in the case of a forked repo?

Comment: @matt: yes, with a forked repository you need to use the `refs/pull/<number>/head` trick. You can also get `refs/pull/<number>/merge`, if their automatic merge worked; if that ref does not exist, their automatic merge failed (with merge conflicts). I have never bothered with their auto-merge commit itself though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your pull request got accepted.
As the modified branch is test_branch. Change the branch on your local editor to test_branch and pull. Then all the changes would be visible.

Comment: I have forgot to shash that on my local editor, so in my local editor I have nothing , all I have is this pull request , how can I get that change of pull request to my local editor?

Comment: @AnkitKumar Try these:
1. `git pull origin test_branch`
2. checkout to test_branch branch and then git pull

Comment: @AnkitKumar First check if the pull request got accepted

Comment: open the pull request url and click on the button `Open with` then Click on `Github CLI` 
 copy that url `gh _ _ _` run that in the terminal hope that help.